# Variable return undefined even assigned in async function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

Hi guys I was working on a Async Function and I want it to return a name that I get from some other API calls.
My code are as below:

`apiAccessor.ts`

```
async registerName(): Promise<any>{
        try{
            await client.register((error, result) => {
                if(error){
                    console.error(`Error register name: ${error}`);
                }
                else{
                    console.log('Registered Successfully!');
                    this.assignedPlace = result.assignedPlace;
                    console.log(this.assignedPlace);
                }
            });
            return this.assignedPlace;
        }
        catch (error) {
            this.logger.error(error.name, error.message);
        }
```

`main.ts`

```
async function nameAssigner() {
    let place = await client.registerName();
    console.log(place);
}

nameAssigner();
```

The problem is, the console.log in `main.ts` will always run first (even if I put the console.log inside `then` promise callback) and giving me `undefined` value while after some time the code in `apiAccessor.ts` had finished, the console.log in `apiAccessor.ts` gave me the correct value I want. However this does not seems to be returned to the `main.ts` as expected.

How can I return the value or let the `main.ts` wait for the function to run complete first?

Thanks for the reads and appreciates if anyone could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that client.register does not return a promise, it takes a call back function that is run internally but does not return a promise. You need to create a promise and resolve it in your callback function and then await the result from the promise.

```
async registerName(): Promise<any>{
    try{

         let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            client.register((error, result) => {
              if(error){
                reject(`Error register name: ${error}`);
              }
              else{
                console.log('Registered Successfully!');
                resolve(result.assignedPlace);
                console.log(this.assignedPlace);
              }
          });
        });
        this.assignedPlace = await promise;
        return this.assignedPlace;
    }
    catch (error) {
        this.logger.error(error.name, error.message);
    }
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks for the solution!!! I'll have to dig more on the Promise part to understand all this.Deeply appreciates the help!!

Comment: The thing to understand is that async/awaits is just syntactic sugar to wrap promises. You need to understand how promises work and then async/awaits will be easier to understand. If you are ready for a propper async challenge then have a look at RxJs. I haven't used a promise in ages as I do all async operations with observables these days. But baby steps, get on top of promises first.

Comment: I see, okay I will read about Promise first before going on observables, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

From your code it looks like `client.register((error, result) => {` uses a callback and is not returning a Promise. Therefore your `await` in front of it doesn't do what you think. You can wrap your call to `client.resolve` with a `Promise` and only resolve/reject it once the callback gives you the result.

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  try {
    client.register((error, result) => {
      if(error){
        console.error(`Error register name: ${error}`);
        return reject(error);
      }
      else{
        console.log('Registered Successfully!');
        return resolve(result.assignedPlace); 
      }
    });
  }
  catch (error) {
    this.logger.error(error.name, error.message);
    return reject(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly the problem, I guess I'll have to read more about Promise to understand all this, thanks for the help!!

Comment: no problem - they can be tricky to get your mind around, but it's worth understanding them fully - experiment and you'll soon get the hang of it.